# PS command on this program

Tags: c, linux

In an assignment, I wrote 2 programs that do the same thing, but one of them uses threads. What I'm asked to do is to stop the programs while they are running and use the `ps` command to compare the two programs, the problem is that I don't know how to do this, I wanted to try stopping the programs using `^z` but the programs execute so fast that I can't even do it, is there a way to do what I'm asked to do? is using functions like sleep will help me? or does it affect the results of the `ps` command?

Here're the programs that I wrote in case it helps and I can modify them to do what I want.

without threads:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int mat[100][100];  // Declare the array

    // Generate the values for the array
    for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 100; col++) {
            mat[row][col] = row * 5 + col / 3 + col;
        }
    }

    // Sum up the values in the array
    int sum = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 100; col++) {
            sum += mat[row][col];
        }
    }

    // Print the result
    printf("Sum of all values in mat: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

with threads:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 100  // Number of threads (one for each column)
#define ROWS 100  // Number of rows in the array
#define COLS 100  // Number of columns in the array

int mat[ROWS][COLS];  // Array to store the values
int sums[COLS];  // Array to store the sums for each column

// Thread function to sum up a column of the array
void* sum_column(void* arg) {
    int col = (int)arg;  // Column to sum up

    // Sum up the values in the column
    int sum = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        sum += mat[row][col];
    }

    // Store the result in the sums array
    sums[col] = sum;

    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];  // Threads

    // Generate the values for the array
    for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            mat[row][col] = row * 5 + col / 3 + col;
        }
    }

    // Create a thread for each column to sum it up
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        pthread_create(&threads[col], NULL, sum_column, (void*)col);
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        pthread_join(threads[col], NULL);
    }

    // Sum up the values in the sums array
    int sum = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        sum += sums[col];
    }

    // Print the result
    printf("Sum of all values in mat: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Increase `ROWS` and `COLS` (and the equivalent `100`s in the non-threaded version) so there's a lot more work to do?

Comment: Add sleeps in your for loops or use really massive matrices.

Comment: Use the [`time`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) command to time the two programs? Run each program a few times to get an average you can use for comparison. Also remember to build with optimizations enabled, timing, benchmarking or profiling debug-builds doesn't give any useful details.

Comment: @AKX I'm asked to use this size of a matrix

Comment: @Pam it won't affect the results of the ps command?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks I'll search how to use this command and try it!

Comment: Ah, @Feras, my C is rusty. You could include printf statements (different for each thread) and watch them interleave. printf statements sometimes help slow things down. Or, you could wrap them up in while(1) loops so they run repeatedly until killed.

Comment: Oh, or breakpoints? That’d stop the program.